# Ошибка Parse error: syntax error, unexpected

Tags: php, отладка, hosting, settings

На localhost работало, а при переносе на хостинг начало выдавать ошибку:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '}' in
>   /home/taradajk/bti-zp.com.ua/www/wp-content/themes/bti/phones.php on
>   line 46

Привожу этот участок кода:

```
function widget($args, $instance) {
    extract( $args );
        $phone1 = $instance['phone1'];
        $phone2 = $instance['phone2'];
        $phone3 = $instance['phone3'];
        $office = $instance['office'];
        $email  = $instance['email'];

        echo $before_widget; ?>

        <h3><i class="fa fa-phone" aria-hidden="true"></i> Звоните</h3>
            <ul class="phones">
                <?php if($phone1): ?><li><?php echo $phone1; ?></li><? endif ?>
                <?php if($phone2): ?><li><?php echo $phone2; ?></li><? endif ?>
                <?php if($phone3): ?><li><?php echo $phone3; ?></li><? endif ?>
            </ul>
            <a data-remodal-target="callme" class="recallme"><i class="fa fa-question-circle" aria-hidden="true"></i> Задать вопрос</a>

        <?php if($email): ?><h3><i class="fa fa-envelope-o" aria-hidden="true"></i> Пишите</h3>
        <p><?php echo $email; ?></p><? endif ?>

        <?php if($office): ?><h3><i class="fa fa-home" aria-hidden="true"></i> Приходите</h3>
        <p><?php echo $office; ?></p><? endif ?>

            <div class="remodal" data-remodal-id="callme">
                <button data-remodal-action="close" class="remodal-close"></button>
                <h1>Хотите задать вопрос?</h1>
                <p>Укажите свое имя и мобильный телефон, а мы перезвоним!</p>
                <?php echo do_shortcode('[contact-form-7 id="60" title="Задать вопрос"]'); ?>
            </div>

        <?php echo $after_widget;
}
```

То есть, как видите, синтаксических ошибок нет. Может быть дело в настройках PHP? Какие параметры отвечают за проверку синтаксиса?

Comment: В смысле нет синтаксических ошибок если у вас `<?php echo $after_widget;` а дальше сразу `}` ...... а еще внутри  внезапно `echo $before_widget; ?>`  и это называется  нет ошибок? А на локалхосте все работало видимо потому, что вы отключили всякое отображение ошибок..........и вообще эта функция что для javascript или для php?

Comment: @АлексейШиманский жесть, чего только на SO не увидишь)))) Почему то в моих мануалах (когда изучал php) такого не было)

Comment: @Bogdan как минимум `?>` поставьте после `<?php echo $after_widget;` (закрывающий тег интерпритатора)

Comment: @ВасилийБарбашев, чтобы получить еще два бага: ошибка парсинга + левая закрывающая скобочка на выводе? Проблему я указал в [этом комменте](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/513218/%D0%9E%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%BA%D0%B0-parse-error-syntax-error-unexpected#comment625094_513222)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема действительно в echo:

```
echo $before_widget;
echo $after_widget;
```

...потому что должны выводиться так:

```
echo $args['before_widget'];
echo $args['after_widget'];
```

о чем я узнал в [примере](https://codex.wordpress.org/Widgets_API) по разработке виджетов для Wordpress. То есть вся функция выглядит так:

```
public function widget( $args, $instance ) {
        echo $args['before_widget'];
        if ( ! empty( $instance['title'] ) ) {
            echo $args['before_title'] . apply_filters( 'widget_title', $instance['title'] ). $args['after_title'];
        }
        echo __( 'Hello, World!', 'text_domain' );
        echo $args['after_widget'];
    }
```

Что интересно, PHP 5.4 не возмущается при наличии такой ошибки.

Comment: Может быть потому, что у вас отключено отображение ошибок, а на хостинге нет?

Comment: а вас не смущает наличие [`extract()`](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.extract.php)? Его работа как раз в этом и заключается: достать из массива в локальные переменные указанные там значения. Т.е. после `extract($args);` можно писать `echo $before_widget;` вместо `echo $args['before_widget'];`

Comment: а проблема у вас скорее всего в том, что руки надо поотрубать тому, кто это писал. `<? endif ?>` - что такое? Точка с запятой вроде как не нужна (хотя тоже по рукам надавать надо), а вот использование коротких тегов вместо с простыми (или как их там) - чревато отрубанием рук по самые уши, здесь даже `grep -Pr '<\?[^p=]' *` не спасет. Хостинг скорее всего не разрешил их использование, потому на localhost все работало, а здесь нет

Comment: @BOPOH - пол беды `echo`...... если написать `echo $args['before_widget'];` то возникает вопрос, а откуда там `html` теги   без `echo`? или это меня только смущает?...... в общем все это полный капец

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, это нормально, особенно если вспомнить как php появился. Все, что между `?>` и `<?php` условно можно считать как `echo '...'`

Comment: @BOPOH Это рукалицо)))

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/38424/discussion-between-bopoh-and--).

Answer (score 2):

1. в начале кода нет открывающегося тэга `<?php`, но так как это фрагмент он наверное есть выше в вашем коде;
2. возможно на хостинге не включено использование коротких тэгов `<?`, поменяйте их на `<?php`;

Answer (score -2):

Используйте IDE например PhpStorm
[image: Вот IDE подсветило что ошибка]

Comment: `extract()` вас не смущает? а ведь из-за него именно это работает как надо, проблема в другом - смотри другие ответы либо мой коммент к ответу автора

Comment: @BOPOH Спасибо! Понял!